# Ubuntu 17.10 reboot problem

Tags: system-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu (v 17.10) for the first time and was suggested to reboot the system.

Ubuntu cannot reboot:

> **[ 9934.778997] systemd-journald[955]: failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected**

Comment: Can you provide a full error message? Also the version of your Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. The error keeps appearing just with different numbers in the brackets.